# Destructuring an array is removing the possible undefined value from the type

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to get typescript to not ignore the possibility that an array could be empty when destructuring? For example in this snippet

```
const numbers: number[] = [];
const [n] = numbers;

type T = typeof n;
```

The type `T` evaluates to `number`, but it should evaluate to `number | undefined` since the value of `n` is `undefined`.

Comment: https://github.com/danielnixon/eslint-plugin-total-functions#total-functionsno-unsafe-destructuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Tnumber = number | undefined;
const numbers: Tnumber[] = [];
const [n] = numbers;

type T = typeof n;

const one: T = undefined;
const two: T = 5;
```

Create a new type `Tnumber`. Later on you the inferred type `T` can be either number or undefined.

Interestingly, `typeof n` is `undefined`. From this behaviour it looks like the Typescript compiler infers the type of the destructured value from the original type of the array, rather than it's current value.